# Listview with CursorAdapter getCheckedItemIds not returning _ids

Tags: android-cursoradapter

Listview with CursorAdapter 
SetchoiceMode is multiple

getCheckedItemIds is returning position rather than _ids
and my adapter is also stable

do you know the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

My cursor adapter had overridden below method

@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

```
    return position;
}
```

i deleted this, now its working fine